# Is there an equation to find the standard deviation of a list deterministic-ally?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, means

Say I have many lists of random number between 0 and 10 inclusive, and this list has 100 values.

the lists will look something like this:

- [9 9 4 7 0 5 8 3 ... 1 9 2 5 6 6 4 2 0 1 9 8]
- [6 0 1 8 6 9 6 4 ... 6 4 3 10 9 2 3 0 3 1 3 10]
- [0 9 2 5 6 7 8 8 ...  0 4 1 7 5 9 2 2 3 6 1 9]

the average value of this list will be close to 5. Is there an equation to find the standard deviation without going through the whole sum((distancetomean)^2) etc...

Comment: But "the whole sum... etc." is a "deteministic" formula for the standard deviation.  There's a typical trick that involves a single pass, to sum $x_i$'s for the mean (average) and at the same time sum $x_i^2$.  The standard deviation can be expressed in terms of both sums.

Comment: If the numbers are chosen independently, and a equally likely, one can compute the *theoretical* standard deviation of the *process*, just as there is a way to show that the mean of the process is $5$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, ok... and how is that done?...

Comment: I am not sure what random variable you want the variance of. For individual entries we use $E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$ The expectation of $X^2$ is $(1/11)(0^2+1^2+\cdots 10^2)$, which is $35$, Subtract $5^2$, we get that the variance is $\sqrt{10}$. But the standard deviation of the average of the answers is much smaller, it is $(1/\sqrt{100})\sqrt{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find standard deviations of a lot of datasets of this kind, you should consider using a statistical calculator that is
programmed to find SDs, or using statistical software.

R is excellent software and free from www.r-project.org. 
Just follow the path to install R on your Windows, Mac, or UNIX
computer.

The
package is extensive and some of the explanations may seem
technical.

But here how to find the standard deviation of a
list. First, use c-notation and commas to enter the data.
Proofread, give the data vector a name, for example `x` and
then type `sd(x)`.

```
 x = c(1,5,6,7,3,4,9,7)
 sd(x)
 [1] 2.54951
```

The [1] in brackets just indicates the answer.

While, you're at it, you can find the
variance, mean, and median.

```
 > var(x)
 [1] 6.5
 > mean(x)
 [1] 5.25
 > median(x)
 [1] 5.5
```

However, there is no way to get around using a messy formula
to get the standard deviation. When you use R, the software
is just using the formula for you.